# Has the table name in SQL for Wordpress changed from WP_posts to WPCS_post?

Tags: customization, sql, cdn

I ran this query in SQL in PhyMyAdmin

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/','https://www.cdn.example.com/');

Though it ran, then gave ERROR wp_posts' doesn't exist.

Then I opened the tables and saw that a name exists as WPCS_Post.

(Though my site runs good, just wanted to add a CDN for storing static files)

I tried searching but found nothing to help me out. Can someone help?
Thanks
Is it the new name for WP_posts?

[image]

Has the table name in SQL for Wordpress changed from WP_posts to WPCS_post?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a new name. The database prefix is configurable during install. By default it’s `wp_`, but in this case it just happens to have been configured to `wpcs_`.

Comment: Thanks. It never occurred to me the significance. Now I will note all what I wrote during install.